# Зациклить функцию в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна функция, которая будет вызываться таким образом:

```
func(10)(20)(30)()
```

и возвращать сумму значений во всех скобках (в данном случае - 60). Последние скобки должны быть пустые.

```
def func(a):
    def func2(b):
        return a + b

    return func2
```

Должно получиться вот так.

```
assert(add(100)()).toBe(100)
assert(add(20)(30)()).toBe(50)
assert(add()()).toBe(0)
assert(add(20)(30)(-10)(34)()).toBe(74)
assert(add(20)(30)(0)()).toBe(50)
assert(add(-20)(0)(0)()).toBe(-20)
assert(add(-20)(0)(0)(0)(10)()).toBe(-10)
assert(add(10)(10)(-10)(10)(10)(10)(10)(10)()).toBe(60)
```

Comment: Напиши вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только тебе, но и всем остальным.

Answer (score 1):

Внешняя нужна только как контейнер для итоговой переменной, а во внутренней, если аргументов на входе нет, возвращаем результат, в противном случае, суммируем все аргументы и возвращаем ссылку на саму себя

```
def myadd(*b):
    a = [0]
    def f2(*b):
        if  len(b):
            a[0] += sum(b)
            return f2
        return a[0]
    return f2(*b)


 myadd(10)(10)(-10)(10)(10)(10)(10)(10)()  # 60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(value=0, acc=0):
    if value is None:
        return acc
    else:
        return lambda v=None: func(v, acc+value)

print(func(10)(10)(-10)(10)(10)(10)(10)(10)()) # 60
```

То же самое через вложенную функцию вместо лямбды:

```
def func(value=None, acc=0):
    if value is None:
        return acc
    else:
        def func1(v=None):
            return func(v, acc+value)

        return func1
```

P.S. единственно, эти варианты выдают ошибку на этом: `func()()`

Чтобы на такой вызов выдавало 0, нужно изменить вот так:

```
def func(value=0, acc=0):
    if value is None:
        return acc
    else:
        return lambda v=None: func(v, acc+value)
```

Но тогда `print(func())` выдаст что-то вроде `<function func.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f30e07e4b70>`. Какой вариант примет проверяющая система - трудно сказать.