# Функция сложения с множественным вызовом

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужна помощь с функцией сложения которая принимает несколько раздельных аргументов.

```
add(100)() //100
add(30)(30)() // 60
add()() // 0
add(10)(10)(-10)(10)(10)(10)(10)(10)() //60
```

Есть вот такое решение

```
var add = (function() {
   let sum = 0;
   let count = function(operand = 0) {
       if(operand) {
           sum += operand;
           return count;
       } else {
           return sum;
       }
   }
   return count;
})();
```

Но данное решение не проходит тест с пустым вызовом, и при последующих вызовах новая сумма добавляется к предыдущей. Сразу скажу, что решения с использованием toString, valueOf, apply, bind тоже не прошли тесты. Может кто что подсказать, или предложить другое решение? Буду благодарен

Comment: неохота переписывать еще раз, вот тут для питона, но это тоже самое - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042652/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/1042663#1042663

Comment: убери `()` вот тут `})();`

Answer (score 2):

Приведенное в вопросе почти рабочее, осталось только убрать лишний вызов функции при присваивании переменной `add`, и сделать sum - параметром в первой функции, что будет начальным значением:

```js
var add = (function(sum = 0) {
   let count = function(operand = 0) {
       if(operand) {
           sum += operand;
           return count;
       } else {
           return sum;
       }
   }
   return count;
});

console.log(add(100)()) //100
console.log(add(30)(30)()) // 60
console.log(add()()) // 0
console.log(add(10)(10)(-10)(10)(10)(10)(10)(10)()) //60
```

Comment: скажите я могу прописать в комментарии как я понял работу кода ( я сомневаюсь что правильно его понял ... )

Comment: @Leks, все могут писать комментарии

Comment: тогда я в ответ могу прописать как я понял код ? а то в комментах будет сложно (для меня) объяснить ?

Comment: @Leks, в ответах должны быть ответы

Comment: sum = 0 или operand = 0 сработают только в том случае если add()() без аргументов ?

Comment: @Leks, это [параметры по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) - если параметр не передан, ему присваивается указанное значение